# Automatic conversion from string to date in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, date, jstl

I am not sure why the following code works:
`str` is a date in the format `2011-11-04 15:54:48.38`. It is a string.
When executing the following code:

```
<fmt:parseDate var="xxx" type="date" pattern="y-M-d H:m:s" value="${str}" />
xxx: <c:out value="${xxx}"></c:out><br />
xxx.time: <c:out value="${xxx.time}"></c:out><br />
str.time: <c:out value="${str.time}"></c:out><br />
str: <c:out value="${str}"></c:out><br />
```

I get this output

```
xxx: Fri Nov 04 15:54:48 GMT 2011
xxx.time: 1320422088038
str.time: 1320422088380
str: 2011-11-04 15:54:48.38
```

How is that possible? Is there any automatic conversion in place for the `str.time` value? How do these conversions work?

Comment: What servletcontainer and EL implementation? What does `<c:out value="${str.class.name}" />` say? After all, I think you're not running the code you think you're running. This one should throw a `PropertyNotFoundException` on `${str.time}`.

Comment: @BalusC The class is `java.sql.Timestamp`. Now is clear :) If you feel to give an aswere I'll mark it as best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not running the code you think you're running. This one should definitely throw a `PropertyNotFoundException` on `${str.time}`. To naildown it, add the following line to find out what `${str}` *actually* is.

```xml
<c:out value="${str.class.name}" />
```

It's apparently a class which prints the given string format on `toString()` and has a `getTime()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that output because the "getTime()" of a Date object returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by the Date object.

**Edit:**

Use: http://www.epochconverter.com/

And put in the seconds outputs, you'll see it corresponds back to your dates.

Comment: That isn't the question. `${str}` is a `String`, not a `Date`, yet the `${str.time}` seemingly works. That's where the question is all about.